# Sequence generation in MongoDB

Tags: java, oracle, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm working on a project in which the backend has primarily been Oracle SQL. The project is done in java with spring-mvc/spring-data/and hibernate.

For doing simple insertions into a table we've annotated our DAO classes with the @SequenceGenerator annotation. This works nicely with Oracle as the Sequence concept is native to Oracle. We're trying to simulate the same thing conceptually with MongoDB. I've looked at this documentation here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

This document suggests to create a separate collection from the underlying collection you want to insert into. In this case, create a "counters" collection in which you just insert a single document with your key "_id" => "userid" and you have a key "seq" => 0 (or some integer).

Then, you create a separate javascript function that can atomically increment that sequence. Finally, when you want to create new documents in your underlying collection, just call the javascript function and set your key "_id" to whatever that javascript returns (in this case an incremented value).

**My question is:**

Is there any other suggested approach for creating a sequence as suggested by the MongoDB documentation? Any drawbacks? Or is this a reliable approach?

Thanks.

Comment: I thing that is the best option for now in mongodb. Autoincrement is not a good id in mongodb

Comment: Questions about auto-increment fields have been asked many times on StackOverflow. I linked to one above. If you just need a unique ID, MongoDB already has that with an `ObjectId`.  It would be better if you explained why you need an auto-incrementing field.